# Ajax Request Always Throws an Error

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function loaded() {
    var xmldoc,
    currenttime = new Date().getTime(),
    req,
    address = 'http://webservices.foo.com/eSignalQuotes/eSignalQuotes.asmx/GetDelayedQuotes?',
    symbols = 'symbols=' + '+c,s,ct,zw,kw,adm+', 
    cusip = '&cusip=',
    fields = '&fields=' + 'desc,month,year,recent,netchg,-decimal',
    type = '&type=' + 'future,stock,index',
    dispfullname = '&dispfullname=' + 'true',
    datefmt = '&datefmt=',
    timefmt = '&timefmt=',
    timestamp = '&' + Math.floor(currenttime/3600000),
    query = address + symbols + cusip + fields + type + dispfullname + datefmt + timefmt + timestamp;
    ;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    req.addEventListener('error', function(e) {alert('Error');}, false);
    req.addEventListener('load', function(e) {xmldoc = req.responseText;}, false);
    req.open('GET', query, true);
    req.send();

}
```

That's what my code looks like, and it always throws an error in Safari and Firefox. The crazy thing is if I remove the event listeners, and change the response type to `responseText`, Internet Explorer gives me output. I tried `overrideMimetype`, but that didn't seem to help. If I check the response in Firefox or Safari, I get `null`. I'm at a loss, and any help would be appreciated.

I should mention that I'd prefer to avoid any 3rd party libraries for this.

Update:
The error occurs during the `progress` event, and if I check `.lengthComputable` I get `false`

Update 2:
Safari sheds more light on the issue:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem which is valid querystring syntax.

Comment: If I enter the address into a browser, it hits the service correctly.

@epascarello: e.message gives me 'undefined'

Comment: you have an extra semicolon `;` after your last variable declaration.

Comment: @epascarello: absolutely right, I'll remove the comment, and edit my answer... for some reason, I can't quite delete my comment ATM... hmz

Comment: There is no `e.message` hence why it is undefined.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with what I can query from an error event. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming it's related to the service. Or, possibly, your firewall/antivirus.

Comment: @Llepwryd do a `console.log(e)` to inspect your error object.

Comment: @Schmiddty Thanks. The error object is [object ProgressEvent]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, but it seems to me that the issue involved cross-site communication. What I ended up doing was having a PHP script download the file then I used javascript to get it locally.

```
<?php
    $mark = $_GET['mark'];
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc -> preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xmldoc -> formatOutput = true;
    $xmldoc -> load($mark);
    unlink('fenced.xml');   
    echo $xmldoc -> save('fenced.xml');
?>
```

Javascript:

```
localreq.open('GET', 'fenced.xml', true);
localreq.addEventListener('load', function(e) {xmldoc = localreq.responseXML;}, false);
localreq.send();
```